# php unexpected dot , where is the issue?

Tags: php, syntax

```
require 'DBConfig/MySqlConfiguration.php';

class DataBase{

    static private $MysqlDSN = **"mysql:host=" .** DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_DATABASE;

}
```

all constants are from the required file using define, it tells me at "mysql:host=" .
that its a syntax error for unexpected '.' or ',' ';' and gives error, whats the reason ?

Comment: Property declarations can only take constant/literal values, not expressions. (In current [PHP versions](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/const_scalar_exprs).)

Comment: You can try this: `class DataBase{
    static private $MysqlDSN;
    function __construct(){
        self::$MysqlDSN = "mysql:host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_DATABASE;
    }
}`

Comment: Worked where I put it inside a function